# How to utilize Axios/Fetch in Google Apps Script with Clasp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-apps-script, axios, clasp

### The Setup

- I am utilizing https://github.com/labnol/apps-script-starter *(contains clasp, babel and webpack)* and set it up correctly in order to work on a Google Sheets Addon.
- I am using Quokka.js + Node within VS Code for prototyping

### The Goal

I started developing sidebars and initial functions and everything works great. Now I want to work with Rest APIs and be able to work with the output both in Node.js as well as in the Google Sheets Addon I am building.

*I understand the following premises:*

- Node doesn't support UrlFetchApp.fetch
- GAS doesn't support native fetch (due to lack of the window and dom objects)

So I decided to test out

- babel-polyfill (this seems to work fine on its own)
- axios (causing issues)

use to handle promises, in order to allow the prototyping in node yet also get the same outcome in the browser.

### The Challenge

Within node, everything works as expected, however once I add

```js
const axios = require('axios');
```

to any .js file in my project I receive the following error when trying to push the code via Clasp.

```
{ code: 400, errors: [ { message: 'Syntax error: Missing name after . operator.', line: ..., domain: 'global', reason: 'badRequest' } ] }
```

The given line throwing the error is `module.exports.default = axios;`

Once I comment out this line, the Clasp push works, but axios isn't working in the GAS environment. (I also tried Fetch Polyfills (like cross-fetch) but run into the same issues)

Any ideas on how to accomplish my goal would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide both the scripts of Google Apps Script and Node.js? Of course, please remove your personal information.